# How can I make Visual Studio Code auto format the code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I make **Visual Studio Code** auto format to adequately render my methods and loops indented?
Although I tried `Ctrl + K` and `Ctrl + D`, they didn't work for me.

Comment: You can press `Control + Shift + P` or `Command + Shift + P` (Mac) to open the command palette and type "settings" and then select "Preferences: Open User Settings" option.
Search for "format on save" setting and check the checkbox. Whenever you save your file, it get formatted automatically.

Comment: Done. Thanks for making my life easier with something that should just have been a checkbox in VSC settings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can press `Control + Shift + P` or `Command + Shift + P` (Mac) to open the command palette and type "settings" and then select "Preferences: Open User Settings" option. Search for "format on save" setting and check the checkbox. Whenever you save your file, it gets formatted automatically.